# проблема с реализацией секундомера в handler

Tags: java, android, android-handler, java-timer

Имеется проблема, с Handler.

```
    private void startTimer() {
    cancelTimer();
    handler = new Handler();
    final MovementMethod movementMethod = new ScrollingMovementMethod();
    handler.postDelayed(timer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (lastSensorValues != null && Bt_On == true) {
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(xLastValue,AnalogData), true, tch);
            }
            xLastValue+=DELAY_TIMER;
            time+=DELAY_TIMER;
            handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY_TIMER);
        }
    }, DELAY_TIMER);
}

private void cancelTimer() {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(timer);
    }
}
```

Вот код. Если в качестве параметра DELAY_TIMER установить значение 1000 или 100, то таймер работает плюс минус нормально, однако если установить DELAY_TIMER на 1-100(мне желательно 3), то случается какая-то фигня, и время начинает протекать иначе (переменная time к примеру не будет увеличиваться на 1000 миллисекунд каждую секунду). МОжете подсказать пожалуйста в чем тут может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я не прав но для таких вещей существуют потоки.

```
long wait = 5; //5s
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long alreadyWait = 0;
            while(alreadyWait < wait) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); //ждём секунду
                    alreadyWait++;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //make Handler
            System.out.println("Отчёт времени закончен");
        }
    }).start();
```

В таком случае создается отдельный поток, который можна приспать на секунду и не тормозить при этом всю программу.

Answer (score -1):

`handler.postDelayed` предназначено для задержки выполнения какого-либо кода.

Используйте следующий код таймера

```
Timer timer_main = new Timer();
timer_main.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask_Receiver(), 0, 500); 

//
public class UpdateTimeTask_Receiver extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               // UI 
            }
        });
    }
}
```